# How to position a List using ZStack & Geometry?

Tags: autocomplete, geometry, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to position a ListView directly below a text field, using a ZStack and the field's geometry - its position and size. This is with a view toward creating an autocomplete picklist

Setting the offset only appears to half work.

So far it looks as follows.

Emulator and device appears as on the right:

[image]

Some useful information here:

https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    @State private var firstname = ""
    @State private var lastname = ""
    @State private var townCity = ""

    @State private var rect: CGRect = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .topLeading){
            VStack{
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Firstname", text: $firstname)
                        TextField("Lastname", text: $lastname)

                        ZStack{
                            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                                TextField("Town/City", text: self.$townCity)
                                    .background(GeometryGetterV2(rect: $rect))
                            }
                            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        }
                        Button("Save") {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            SelectionsPickerV2()
                .offset(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y)
                //.offset(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
                .frame(
                    width: rect.size.width,
                    height: rect.size.height * 7)
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack")
    }
}

struct SelectionsPickerV2: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            List{
                Text("Sydney, Australia")
                Text("New York, New York")
                Text("London, UK")
                Text("Paris, France")
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .border(Color.red, width: 1)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct GeometryGetterV2: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.makeView(geometry: geometry)
        }
    }

    func makeView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .named("myZstack"))
            //self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
            //self.rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }

        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Xcode version are you using, it looks nice with mine (Xcode 11.2, beta 11B41).

[image]

Comment: Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44). The screenshot was of the emulator. Which is different from the preview and includes a navbar at the top (added a second screenshot). Also, an actual device renders the same as the emulator. Possibly the addition of a tabbar and navbar confuses the placement calculations.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. Your sample was misleading because it does not reproduce the problem. When you post code, try to make it something that other people can paste on Xcode and reproduce the problem without having to invest time on that. It's for your benefit! Back to the problem, the issue you are having, is the coordinates you are generating with the GeometryReader are global, however, in your offset, you are offsetting from the ZStack's origin (which is not (0,0) when you have the NavigationView top bar. Later I'll try to update the code for a working solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking to post a simplified version of the code (now redone). Still, the offset should be zero, so the placement is not correct. I tried the use of named, local and global coordinates. For example, .coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack")

Comment: Not really an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Comments do not allow images.

Answer (score 0):

As many mentioned, your `ZStack` being the top level view gets geometry calculations wrong as the navigation bar gets added, etc. Probably just another SwiftUI bug.

To fix it just embed your `ZStack` inside a new parent view.

```
struct TestView: View {

    // ...

    var body: some View {
        VStack { // New parent view
            ZStack (alignment: .topLeading){
                // ...
            }
            SelectionsPickerV2()
                .offset(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y)
                .frame(
                    width: rect.size.width,
                    height: rect.size.height * 7)
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack") // Fixed coordinate space
        }
    }
}
```